# Maximum likelihood classification, Landsat: Why to exclude thermal band?

Tags: gis, arcgis, landsat

I search for an argument (which I could cite, ideally) to support my decision to **exclude Thermal band 6 from Maximum likelihood classification** (MLC) of Landsat (5-7) imagery. 
To my knowledge, the thermal band 6 is suggested to exclude from MLC because of its coarser spatial resolution (~ 120 m), comparing to another bands (30 m).

Please, **can you suggest me some papers resulting this**? The only one I've found is: 
http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXIV/part1/paper/00077.pdf
*... a classification utilizing all of the TM bands
(excluding the thermal band due to its coarse spatial resolution) ...*

Please, do you have suggestions for another papers/handbooks?

Answer (score 0):

While many papers such as the one you cite do indeed note that they exclude the  thermal band(s) when performing classification with Landsat images, I cannot recall ever reading a paper that rigorously showed that classification was improved as a result.

In fact, it is not hard to find papers that show **including** the thermal band(s) can actually increase classification accuracy. See http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/7/7/8368 for one example.

I personally include the thermal bands in my classifications (after downscaling to 30m). Sure, the native spatial resolution is not as good but spectrally, the information in the thermal band(s) is relatively independent from that in the visible and NIR bands helping me more easily distinguish certain types of LULC.

Comment: Yes, maybe that was my trouble.. If I have included band 6, my classification was very bad.. However, I've never downscaled the thermal band to 30 m. Too late for this work, but maybe next time... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When composting/mosaicing multiple images the thermal band will show greater variation than spectral bands, this may or may not be an issue.

The coarser spatial resolution can also affect accuracy statistics. If multiple samples are selected from the same 60m thermal pixel but assigned to different 30m classified pixels. See the various papers associated with this comment http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/4/288

The thermal band also does not fully overlap the other spectral bands.